# How to debug a test and/or running code in a Docker container from PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a docker-compose file which starts several services, including a backend application running in PHP/Laravel and listening to port 80/443 for web requests (solely to GraphQL requests). I also have PHPUnit in place to test that code.

I have been trying for some hours now to be able to set breakpoints in my code with PhpStorm and correctly debug my code running in the Docker container, but to no avail. I'm sure I don't miss much because there is some debugging I managed to do but it's not enough.

I was able to configure in PhpStorm a remote PHPUnit debug configuration, which runs a specific test method, and it works OK, stopping on the breakpoints in that file. But if I set breakpoints in other files, they are not triggered.

I would like to be able to debug both from PHPUnit tests and from the app running normally, but I at least need to be able to do it from tests.

Here is what I added to the Dockerfile of the application container (relevant part only):

```
RUN ...
&& pecl install xdebug \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.idekey=idekey" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo -e "xdebug.remote_host=$(host `hostname` | grep -om 1 10\..*$)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
```

Here is the CLI Interpreter configured in PhpStorm:
[image]

I also changed Xdebug's port to 9001 both in PhpStorm and in the container (`xdebug.remote_port=9001`.)

Comment: You are using Linux, right? Please load the `phpinfo()` page with your Dockerized web server and check what you have as the `xdebug.remote_host`. Apart from that, please configure [Xdebug remote log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-XDebug) and check if 1) it even makes a connection when you are trying to debug your app 2) what error is there when it fails